# I'm not able to use operator >=~ whereas <=~ works

Tags: perl

```
  $x = 0x90000000;
    $y = 0x9004FFFF;
    $z = 0xB001FFFF;
    if(($y >=~ (/0x9001FFFF||0xB001FFFF/)))
    {
    print "print something!";
    }
    else
    {
        print "print nothing!";
    }
    if(($y <=~ (/0x9004FFFF||0xB001FFFF/)))
    {
    print "print something!";
    }
    else
    {
        print "print nothing!";
    }
```

The actual output is:

```
print nothing!print something!
```

The expected output is:

```
print something!print something!
```

Comment: What do you think the `>=~` and `<=~` operators are supposed to do?

Comment: >=~ checks "greater than or equal to with binding to right hand operands" and <=~ checks "lesser than or equal to  with binding to right hand operands"

Comment: `$y = 0x9004FFFF` : did you mean the string `$y = "0x9004FFFF"` not the number `$y = 2416246783` (which is the decimal number that perl converts the hex constant 0x9004FFFF to)?

Comment: Also, if you used the `warnings` and `strict` pragmas you would catch some errors with your script

Comment: `<=~` is not a perl operator, `$x <=~ /foo/` is interpreted as `($x <= (~/foo/))` where `~` is the bitwise negation operator

Comment: 1)I meant $y = "0x9004FFFF" as hex and perl will convert it to dec.

Comment: Yeah, i do get warnings stating "Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//)"

Comment: Basically im using ' ~' with >= as binding Alternative operator. And my intention here is to check : y >= 0x9004FFFF || y>=B001FFFF.Instead of writing it twice, i used binding operator and wrote "if($y >=~ (/0x9001FFFF||0xB001FFFF/))". But this does'nt work

Comment: You can't just make up arbitrary syntax and expect it to magically work.

Comment: Did you find some code that used such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to check that `$y` is greater than the greatest value in a list. There are some ways to do this, but the simplest is to find the max value and only compare to that:

```
 use List::Utils qw(max);
 if( $y >= max(@list) ) { ... }
```

Or, if you want `$y` to be greater than or equal to a least one of the values, only test the minimum value:

```
 use List::Utils qw(min);
 if( $y >= min(@list) ) { ... }
```

The `grep` in scalar context returns the number of times its condition was satisfied. If you want `$y` to be greater than or equal to two of the values, you check the result of `grep`:

```
 if( 2 <= grep { $y >= $_ } @list ) { ... }
```

Comment: Related tools: `any`, `all` and `none`. List::Util, List::MoreUtils and/or other modules provide these.

Answer (score 1):

The operators >=~ (or <=~) do not exist in perl

```
if(($y >=~ (/0x9001FFFF||0xB001FFFF/)))
```

actually is:

```
if ($y >= (~  ($_=~/0x9001FFFF||0xB001FFFF/) ))
```

as every scalar matches  the empty string this is

```
if ($y >= (~  (1) ))
```

the binary 'not' of 1 in my 64bit perl is 18446744073709551614

so we finally are at

```
if ($y >= 18446744073709551614)
```

which evaluates to false.